# How to reset ejabberd admin password?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I forgot ejabberd admin password.

I've googling a few hours but no solution yet.

Is there any solution to reset password ?

Comment: Just a gotcha to watch out for... If you leave the hostname (e.g. 'myhost') in the installer, and then try to log into the admin console using 'localhost', it will fail, since whatever password you entered is for 'admin' at 'myserver', not 'localhost'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ejabberdctl change_password admin hostname new_password

I changed admin password with this. :)